# Set a Bash Command Return as a Variable

Tags: perl, bash

If we can perform this in Perl It would be fine as well. 
I don't know if this is even possible but this is what i want to be able to do. I am trying to get a memory percentage of memory being used (There may be better ways of doing this, please let me know)

I have this bash command

```
free -m | grep "Mem: " | awk '{print ($3/$2)*100}'
```

This will return a number, but what I want to do is set a variable to the output of the command.

```
So var1= Output of the above command
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
var1=$(free -m | grep "Mem: " | awk '{print ($3/$2)*100}')
```

**Explanation:**

- The `$(...)` syntax is called command substitution in shell.
- It spawns a subshell to execute whatever is inside the parentheses, then returns anything printed out to `stdout` within that subshell.

**Aside:**

The alternative syntax is with backticks:

```
var1=`free -m | grep "Mem: " | awk '{print ($3/$2)*100}')`
```

but it's not the preferred method due to readability and nesting issues.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I forgot to add the "$" before the command. I put the brackets around but no $. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `grep`, if you are using `awk`. You can simplify your command to:

```
var1=$(free -m | awk '/Mem:/{print ($3/$2)*100}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks on the command:

```
export var=`command`
```

Comment: My version of bash doesn't like spaces around the `=` in the variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux (or any Unix with compatible /proc interface), you can get % of used memory this way:

```
var1=$(perl -ne '/(\w+):\s*(\d+)/ and ($mem{$1} = $2) }{ printf "%0.2f", 100 - 100 * $mem{MemFree} / $mem{MemTotal}' /proc/meminfo)
```

Note that is is generally a good idea to subtract buffers & cache (OS caching tends to fill all the available RAM):

```
var2=$(perl -MList::Util=sum -ne '/(\w+):\s*(\d+)/ and ($mem{$1} = $2) }{ printf "%0.2f", 100 - 100 * sum(@mem{qw{Buffers Cached MemFree}}) / $mem{MemTotal}' /proc/meminfo)
```